# Linq Select unique items from groups and get similar item by ID

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var groups = db.Orders.GroupBy(x => x.OwnedOn);
```

Let's suppose groups returns the following results:
Group 1:

```
[0] ID = 3      Name = "Uncharted 4"           OwnerID = 1    Owned On 21/08/2016
[1] ID = 6      Name = "Assassin's Creed"      OwnerID = 3    Owned On 21/08/2016
[2] ID = 4      Name = "Tomb Raider"           OwnerID = 2    Owned On 21/08/2016
```

Group 2:

```
[0] ID = 5      Name = "Assassin's Creed"      OwnerID = 7    Owned On 22/08/2016
```

Group 3:

```
[0] ID = 21     Name = "FIFA 17"               OwnerID = 10    Owned On 23/08/2016
[1] ID = 12     Name = "Crash Bandicoot"       OwnerID = 5    Owned On 23/08/2016
```

Ok. Now I want to perform a Linq which will give me one item from each group with the highest OwnerID.
So expected result would be:

```
[0] ID = 6      Name = "Assassin's Creed"      OwnerID = 3    Owned On 21/08/2016
[1] ID = 5      Name = "Assassin's Creed"      OwnerID = 7    Owned On 22/08/2016
[2] ID = 21     Name = "FIFA 17"               OwnerID = 10    Owned On 23/08/2016
```

Comment: The title may be misleading to what it actually required so please ignore the title and answer the question based on the description.

Comment: And what is your problem? Anyway: the title is very important to future readers, advising them to ignore it will not help anyone. You should definitlly improve it to fit your actual question.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would do the job, I believe:

```
db.Orders.GroupBy(x => x.OwnedOn)
         .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(e => e.OwnerID).First());
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mKqrD4)

Comment: Group cannot contains 0 elements :)

Comment: It makes sense... -_-

Comment: Thanks :) It was great.

Comment: @SimonBelanger however I am curious, what does .Dump do? and I cannot access it through linq.

Comment: @Abz `Dump()` is just a helper in .NET Fiddle to output the content of a variable in the console